# Curvature on bad 2-orbifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

It may a stupid question. As stated in Lang-Fang Wu' paper (JDG 33(1991)) “Bad orbifolds do not admit metrics of constant curvature.  ” Can anyone give a proof or a reference about this statement. How about the case for high-dim orbifold?  Thank you for any comments.

（An orbifold is called bad if it can not be covered by a manifold. For example, the only closed bad 2-orbifold are teardrops and (p,q)-footballs, for which they have only one singular point with order $n$ and two singular points with order $p,q$(which are coprime numbers) resp.）

Comment: It will help if you define a "bad orbifold".

Comment: For 2-dimensional orbifolds I think this is Theorem 13.3.6 In Chapter 13 ( "Orbifolds") of "The Geometry and Topology of Three Manifolds" by W. P. Thurston.

Comment: The idea is that if you have a metric of constant curvature, there exists the so-called developing "map" (a multi-valued map) whose inverse is a covering by a manifold (in 2-D case this manifold is one of the  surfaces of constant curvature.)